# Many to many on List

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

When executing the following code

```
    public static List<Filmler> GetPlayerByMovie(int id)
    {
        var data = from o in db.Oyuncular
                   where o.OyuncularID == id
                   select o;

        return data.ToList();
    }
```

I get this error message:

> Error 1: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' c:\users\furkan\documents\visual
>   studio 2012\Projects\DvdKiralamaFurkanR\DvdKiralamaFurkanR\Service.cs

I have 2 normal tables, and 1 bridge table on SQL. and i want to connect this on Linq. But I couldn't succeed. How can I post back List.

Can you help me ?

Comment: You try to convert `List<Oyuncular>` to `List<Filmler>`. So you get error. check @AD.Net suggestion.

Comment: Once LINQ completes your `data` will be of type `List<Oyuncular>` and your return value type should be `List<Filmler>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static List<Filmler> GetPlayerByMovie(int id)
    {
        var data = from o in db.Oyuncular
                   where o.OyuncularID == id
                   select new Filmler{populate properties here ex Id = o.Id};

        return data.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in you list you supose to return a lollection of object of type Filmler

```
 List<Filmler> GetPlayerByMovie(int id)
```

but you are trying to return an object of type Oyuncular

```
 var data = from o in db.Oyuncular
                   where o.OyuncularID == id
                   select o;
  return data.ToList();
```

you can either return the type   `List<Oyuncular> GetPlayerByMovie(int id)`

or match Filmler with Oyuncular

```
  var data = (from o in db.Oyuncular
                       where o.OyuncularID == id
                       select  new Filmler {//Filmproperty=o.propperty};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [Enumerable.ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method in the linq for this

```
public static List<Filmler> GetPlayerByMovie(int id)
{
    var data = (from o in db.Oyuncular
                where o.OyuncularID == id
                select o).ToList();

    return data;
}
```